# Difference between ethernet and TCP/IP protocol in programming?

Tags: network-programming, ethernet, tcp, raw-ethernet

Say ff a socket is open for Ethernet then is it same as socket in TCP/IP ? In some existing code i have found that, it supports Ethernet protocol, does that mean i can connect to this Ethernet socket using TCP socket client.

I am in confusion, please help.

Thanks in advance
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

A raw ethernet socket, e.g. `SOCK_RAW`, cannot be used for TCP communication without you writing the protocol handler (you don't want to do that). You are expected to know how to serialize/deserialize ethernet frames when a socket is opened in raw ethernet mode. `SOCK_STREAM` is the mode for TCP and the internet is awash with examples of TCP client/server code.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion. Ethernet is a layer 1 and 2 technology in the OSI model and the TCP/IP model. For communicating directly over 802.3, in Linux you can use [packet sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) to directly generate an 802.3 frame and send it out through the NIC. You can also use packets sockets to receive 802.3 frames. Something different is TCP socket, [stream sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html). Use stream sockets for a TCP connection. With a packet socket you can always receive a 802.3 frame containing an IP datagram which contains a TCP segment. However, in order to establish a TCP connection you need to have a TCP communication established between two points. If the code you saw says "Ethernet protcol", you should check it is actually doing, it could just be a misconception on the programmer side. Check the type of socket they are using.